# Querying with a string converted from an array of ints, results in Conversion data type smallint error

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have an array of ints, each int corresponds to an phone ID number in the database.

In my application I convert the array of ints into a string as seen below and use this as an sql parameter.

```
    public IList<Phones> GetPhonesByID(int[] idNumbersInts)
    {
        var idNumbersStr = string.Join(",", idNumbersInts);

        var phones = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Phones>(@"
            SELECT Make,
            Model
            FROM PHONES                                 
            WHERE ID_NUM IN (@idNumbers)",
                new SqlParameter("@idNumbers", idNumbersStr),
                ).ToList();

        return phones;
    }
```

This results in the error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@idNumbers' to data type smallint
```

The challenge I have is that I am working with a legacy database so the fix has to be done entirely in my code and not on the db end.

Comment: Dawson, I couldn't find the parameter '@subjects' in the code you posted. Can u please add it here

Comment: Sorry, that was an error made when simplifying the code to highlight the error. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Are you converting the values witin `idNumbersStr` to `int` before passing them? Use `int.TryParse` to ensure the values are all of the correct type before passing them. [cheat sheet](https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC41784.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL parameters simply don't work like that. SQL parameters are there to help you avoid *SQL injections*, but you are trying to do exactly that: Inject SQL with your string of comma separated integers. Database engine is trying to convert your full *varchar* (string) type parameter value into *smallint*. It doesn't know nor care that you are trying to give it a list.

Now, with integers as parameters to your method you are quite safe to inject those into your SQL straight up.

```
string sqlQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT Make, Model
    FROM PHONES WHERE ID_NUM IN ({0})", idNumberStr);
var phones = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Phones>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

If in some other query you are not using integers but strings, then this approach is a security risk. In that case this next approach is better and it could be use in your current case, too. Be wary that if your list of items grows large, you should consider writing them in a temporary table first and use that in your WHERE clause, so that the database engine doesn't suffocate while trying to parse your list.

```
var sqlParams = list<SqlParameter>();
int index = 0;
foreach (var id in idNumbersInts)
   sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@p" + (index++), id));
string sqlQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT Make, Model
    FROM PHONES WHERE ID_NUM IN ({0})",
    String.Join(",", sqlParams.Select(p => p.ParameterName).ToArray()));
var phones = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Phones>(sqlQuery,
    sqlParams.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need execute sql, try this:

```
var phones = _context.Phones.Where(ph => idNumbersInts.Contains(ph.ID_NUM));
```